# How can I reduce home page and post page thumbnail image when same thumbnail both side

Tags: php, html, wordpress, image, thumbnails

I want to change home page and blog post page thumbnail size. I noticed thumbnail size generate through same class'large' on both pages.

html code is:

```
home page code
<img width="750" height="422" src="https://amazquiz.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/11/amazon-fz-points-weekly-qu…" class="attachment-large size-large wp-post-image" alt="amazon-fz-points-weekly-quiz-answer" itemprop="image" decoding="async" srcset="https://amazquiz.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/11/amazon-fz-points-weekly-qu…" sizes="(max-width: 750px) 100vw, 750px">

Blog post code
<img width="750" height="422" src="https://amazquiz.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/11/amazon-fz-points-weekly-quiz-answer.jpg" class="attachment-large size-large wp-post-image" alt="amazon-fz-points-weekly-quiz-answer">
```

I change tried to change it from funtion.php but no change. Let us know php code editing.